# onKeyUp em input Date

Tags: html5

Preciso fazer um `onKeyUp` em `input Date` de forma que o **usuário** não consiga escolher uma data posterior à data de limite do campo.

Tipo:

```
<input type='date' id='data' name='data' max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required />
```

Não serve `onkey down`. Precisa ser durante a digitação do campo e não na escolha na combo.

Será que tem como bloquear a digitação na text box com html5?

Mas aí o usuário pode retirar...

Está dificil.

Comment: Tudo feito no front-end pode ser alterado. O importante é validar as informações no servidor.

Comment: ok, mas mesmo que alterado, exste uma forma de negar ao usuário que decide digitar na combo ao invés de escolher a data na combo escolher uma data póstuma? Talvez seja ineressante validar a data com jQuey/JavaScript  e  limpara data caso ela seja superior

Comment: Eu nunca deixo o usuário digitar. Sempre coloco a opção de escolher a data através de um DatePicker.

Comment: Tinha colocado uma resposta com `onkeydown='event.preventDefault();'`, mas como vc disse que não serve, eu removi a resposta.

Comment: Lembrando que mesmo que o usuário digite um valor fora do adequado o input se torna inválido. A invalidação do campo funciona, só que apenas evita que o form seja enviado e não que a data seja impedida de ser digitada. De qualquer forma, sem validação no servidor, de nada adianta validações no front-end.

Answer (score 0):

> Será que tem como bloquear a digitação na text box com html5?

Sim. Com o atributo `readonly`.

```
<input type='date' id='data' name='data' max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly />
```

Comment: O `readonly` bloqueia o campo, pelo menos no Opera.

Comment: verdade, bloqueia o campo todo inclusive a popup com o calendário